# Openshift online and client certificate

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, openshift

I need to accept only requests originating from Amazon API Gateway. According to this, I use the client certificate technique ([aws api gateway Client-Side SSL Authentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html)).

How can I install the client certificate into an openshif scalable application based on tomcat?

**UPDATE**

Maybe can I configure the HAPROXY in front of tomcat to accept only client request with a client certificate?

Thank you,
Agostino

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to configure Tomcat so it only accepts requests from HTTPS clients presenting a certain TLS client certificate?

Comment: Yes but in openshift online